# How do I change Grails test report system?

Tags: grails, testing, report, spock, geb

How do I change Grails test report system so that It wont delete test reports after each test and shows date/time? I need this so that I can make a bigger report based on multiple tests.

Comment: In a simple way, you may write your own java/groovy/gradle/bash script. In more complex way, you may write the patch for Grails.

Comment: Is this question original and exists in the single instance? As it seems to me I've answered to very similar (I'd say identical) question already? Was it your question? But I can't found it just now.